# Rcharts Shiny : not reload all variables after just one variable update

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

i've this kind of shiny Highcharts function in shiny

```
h1 <- Highcharts$new()
h1$series(data = test$sites, type="column",name = "Sites Actifs",enabled=T)
h1$series(data = test$alerte, type="column",name = "Sites Alerte")
h1$series(data = test$ID, type="area",name = "CAID", enabled=F)
h1$series(data = test$LD, type="area",name = "MILD")
h1$series(data = test$rat, type="line", name = "Percentile")
h1$series(data = test$epi, type="line", name = "Outbreak")
h1$series(data = test$Temp,  type='line', name = "Temperatures")
h1$series(data = test$ND, type = "line", name = "NDVI")
h1$series(data = test$Pm, type="line",name = "Pmm",enabled=T)
h1$colors('rgba(187, 165, 203, 0.9)', 'rgba(187, 40, 175,0.9)','rgba(255,179,128,.9)','rgba(0,0,128,.4)','rgba(170,0,0, .9)', 'rgba(0,0,0, .9)', 'rgba(243,170,80, .9)','rgba(120,193,102, .9)','rgba(85,153,255,.9)')
h1$legend(symbolWidth = 30)
h1$plotOptions(line=list(marker=list(enabled = F)),area=list(marker=list(enabled = F)))
h1$chart(zoomType = "x1")
h1$exporting(enabled = T)
h1$params$width <- 500
h1$params$height <- 700
h1$xAxis(type='datetime', categories=ref_time, tickInterval = 30)
return(h1)
```

But when i hide some variable (i.e. $sites, $alerte, $Temp) in order to test some hypothesis, if i update another variable (i.e. $rat) all the graph is updated and hidden variables are unhidden.

Do you have a solution to circumvent this "problem"

Thanks

Comment: Not sure exactly of your problem but have you tried with "isolate"?

Comment: It is not exactly that...I have several curves in one graph using (Highcharts). Just parameters for test$epi could be changed by user. I would like hide some curve (i.e. test$ND and test$epi) and in the same time modify the parameters for test$epi...it's ok, but when parameters for test$epi are changed, all the graph is reloaded, and test$ND and test$ep are unhidden....

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure I understand your problem, but say you define a couple of checkboxes in your shiny app that allow you to hide/show a specific series all you need to do is use that with the visible option, e.g.

`h1$series(data = test$ND, type = "line", name = "NDVI", visible=input$show.NDVI)`

The plot will still be generated each time you change a checkbox, but the hidden series will stay the same. Another option might be not to add the series in the first place, e.g.

`if(input$show.NDVI){ 
  h1$series(data = test$ND, type = "line", name = "NDVI", visible=input$show.NDVI)
}`